# mysql, where statement include everything plus more

Tags: mysql, logic

Long and short. I have mysql statement here

```
SELECT 
DATE_ADD(LoadEDate,INTERVAL(6-DAYOFWEEK(LoadEDate)) DAY) AS EndOfWeek, 
    SUM(Linehaul) as LinehaulWeekTotal 
from loads 
GROUP BY WEEK(LoadEDate,3)
```

Ultimately it outputs everything in the week and adds it together based on the week (friday as the end date for visual purposes only.

What is needed is to also include records that contain the column CtrlNum that contain the letter H as well as have records that contain CreateDate (set to via timestamp when the record was entered) of the same week being calculated for.

For example in plain words.

A record could be enter where the LoadEDate is in the previous week (Monday-Sunday week 51) however it was inserted the following week (Monday - Sunday week 52). This means that the calculation should add that total to the week entered instead of the week that LoadEDate is equal to.

This is a true head scratcher for me and any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Selecting one thing and then grouping by a different thing is rarely a great idea.

Comment: Agreed, the problem lies that we have some records are delayed entry and the only way i can figure to make it show properly is to instead of going based on the LoadEDate. If anyone can think of a better way to do it man that would eliminate a lot of hassles (and the fight to make sure everything is put in on time every time is like pulling teeth with toothpicks)